# Replace NaN value of first row in a groupby with value of next row which contains specific value - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame which looks like the following

```
email              month      level
jacob.a@abc.com    jan        EE2 
kylie.l@abc.com    jan        nan
jacob.a@abc.com    mar        MG1 
sumeer.b@abc.com   jan        nan
boris.k@abc.com    jan        nan
kylie.l@abc.com    jun        EE3
cinkil.m@abc.com   jan        nan
sumeer.b@abc.com   apr        PT 
cinkil.m@abc.com   jul        MG1
sumeer.b@abc.com   aug        MG1
sumeer.b@abc.com   sep        MG2 
kylie.l@abc.com    sep        MG3
```

I plan to do a `groupby` to select the first and last rows for each group.

But before I do that, I'd like to replace the first rows of each employee in the that are "nan", with the next row only if it contains either "EE" or "MG"

I was thinking of creating a new column called `level_new`

```
email              month      level     level_new
jacob.a@abc.com    jan        EE2       EE2
kylie.l@abc.com    jan        nan       EE3
jacob.a@abc.com    mar        MG1       MG1
sumeer.b@abc.com   jan        nan       MG1
boris.k@abc.com    jan        nan       nan
kylie.l@abc.com    jun        EE3       EE3
cinkil.m@abc.com   jan        nan       MG1
sumeer.b@abc.com   apr        PT        PT
cinkil.m@abc.com   jul        MG1       MG1
sumeer.b@abc.com   aug        MG1       MG1
sumeer.b@abc.com   oct        MG2       MG2  
kylie.l@abc.com    sep        MG3       MG3
```

so that I could achieve the following `groupby`

```
email              month      level     level_new
jacob.a@abc.com    jan        EE2       EE2
jacob.a@abc.com    mar        MG1       MG1
kylie.l@abc.com    jan        nan       EE3
kylie.l@abc.com    sep        MG3       MG3
sumeer.b@abc.com   jan        nan       MG1
sumeer.b@abc.com   oct        MG2       MG2  
boris.k@abc.com    jan        nan       nan
cinkil.m@abc.com   jan        nan       MG1
cinkil.m@abc.com   jul        MG1       MG1
```

So far, I am only able to select the first and the last rows based on the group by, but this would still select the nan values for the first row of each employee.

```
#get the first and last row of each group
#".nth[-1]" retrieves the last row
#".nth[0]" retrieves the first row
df2 = df.groupby('email', as_index=False).nth([0,-1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `where` to replace values other than "MG" or "EE" with NaN; then `groupby` + `bfill` + `fillna` to fill in NaN values in "level" column with the next value that is either "MG" or "EE" for each "email".

Then use `groupby` + apply a lambda that fetches the index of the first and last value for each "email" as a list + `explode` the list + `drop_duplicates` (in case some emails appear only once) to create a mask that returns True for first and last values for each "email" and False otherwise. Then use this mask to filter the relevant outcome:

```
df['level_new'] = df['level'].fillna(df['level'].where(df['level'].str.contains('MG|EE')).groupby(df['email']).bfill())
out = df.loc[df.groupby('email')['level_new'].apply(lambda x: [x.index.min(), x.index.max()]).explode().drop_duplicates()]
```

Output:

```
               email month level level_new
4    boris.k@abc.com   jan   NaN       NaN
6   cinkil.m@abc.com   jan   NaN       MG1
8   cinkil.m@abc.com   jul   MG1       MG1
0    jacob.a@abc.com   jan   EE2       EE2
2    jacob.a@abc.com   mar   MG1       MG1
1    kylie.l@abc.com   jan   NaN       EE3
11   kylie.l@abc.com   sep   MG3       MG3
3   sumeer.b@abc.com   jan   NaN       MG1
10  sumeer.b@abc.com   sep   MG2       MG2
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the following fuction to process a group:

```
def procGrp(grp):
    if grp.index.size == 1:    # single row only
        return grp
    if pd.isnull(grp.iat[0,2]):
        nxtLev = grp.iat[1,2]  # next "level"
        if ('EE' in nxtLev) or ('MG' in nxtLev):
            grp.iat[0,2] = nxtLev  # set in 1-st row
    # Return first and last row from this group
    return grp.loc[[grp.index[0], grp.index[-1]]]
```

Then group your DataFrame by *email* and apply this function:

```
result = df.groupby('email').apply(procGrp)
```

For your data sample the result is:

```
               email month level
4    boris.k@abc.com   jan   NaN
6   cinkil.m@abc.com   jan   MG1
8   cinkil.m@abc.com   jul   MG1
0    jacob.a@abc.com   jan   EE2
2    jacob.a@abc.com   mar   MG1
1    kylie.l@abc.com   jan   EE3
11   kylie.l@abc.com   sep   MG3
3   sumeer.b@abc.com   jan   NaN
10  sumeer.b@abc.com   sep   MG2
```

As you can see:

- row for *boris.k@abc.com* has also still *NaN*, as this group contains only
  a single row,
- row for *sumeer.b@abc.com* has still *NaN*, as the next row has *level
  == 'PT'*.

You don't even need to create any additional column.